# In what sense the discrete difference operation is "almost" self-adjoint?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

It is well-known that on $L^2[0,1]$, the differential operator $i\frac{d}{dx}$ is self-adjoint with domain of differentiable, periodic functions on $[0,1]$.

Now, let us discretize $[0,1]$, say $B_N:=\{ 0, \frac{1}{N} , \frac{2}{N} , \cdots , 1\}$ for some very large $N$. Next define
\begin{equation}
M(B_N):= \{ f: B_N \to \mathbb{C} \mid f(0)=f(1) \}
\end{equation}
Then, obviously, $M(B_N)$ is a finite dimensional Hilbert space with the inner product given by
\begin{equation}
\langle f , g \rangle:= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{x \in B_N} f(x) \overline{g(x)}
\end{equation}

Using the summation by parts formula and the periodicity conditions, it is not hard to show that the linear operator $i\partial^N : M(B_N) \to M(B_N)$ defined by
\begin{equation}
(i\partial^N f)(x):=iN[f(x+1/N)-f(x)]
\end{equation}
has the adjoint $i\partial^{-N}$ defined by
\begin{equation}
(i\partial^{-N} f)(x):=iN[f(x)-f(x-1/N)]
\end{equation}
with respect to the inner product above.

Thus, in the finite lattice, the difference operator is not exactly self-adjoint, but I see that it is 'almost' self-adjoint for all large $N$'s.

Does this mean that it is possible to have some "almost" orthonormal basis of $M(B_N)$ that are the eigenvectors of $i\partial^N$?

I wonder if this is up to the level of a research question, but have not found any relevant reference myself. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Not an answer, but you could consider central differences instead of forward differences to get a self-adjoint operator. You could also use the discrete Fourier transform to diagonalize the forward difference operator.

Comment: What is a central difference?

Comment: Something like $[f(x+h)-f(x-h)]/(2h)$ (and $[f(x+h)-f(x)]/h$ is called forward and $[f(x)-f(x-h)]/h$ backward difference). They all approximate the derivative…

Comment: I see...thank you!